# `Sink.receiveValue` is not called after `publisher.receive(on: backgroundQueue)`

Tags: ios, swift, combine

With the following code, after I put `receive(on: backgroundQueue)`, the `receiveCompletion` will be called 100%, but the `receiveValue` block is not.

```swift
xxxxPublisher
    .xxxx()
    .receive(on: backgroundQueue)
    .xxxx()
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        // completion code
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        // receive value code
    }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

This seems not a good behavior, are we supposed to not use `receive<S>(on scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil)` in this way? Am I missing something?

Here is the code to reproduce this bug, if you run this code, you will see that `receiveCompletion` is called exactly 300 times, but `receiveValue` is called less than 300.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
for i in 1...300 {
    runPublisher(i)
}
var sinkCompletedIndices = Set<Int>()
var sinkOutputIndices = Set<Int>()

func runPublisher(_ index: Int) {
    [1].publisher
    .receive(on: backgroundQueue)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        NSLog("sink receiveCompletion")
        sinkCompletedIndices.insert(index)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        NSLog("sink receiveValue")
        sinkOutputIndices.insert(index)
    }).store(in: &cancellables)
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
    let diff = sinkCompletedIndices.filter { !sinkOutputIndices.contains($0) }
    NSLog("Difference between completions and outputs \(diff)")
}
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: Why `.receive(on: backgroundQueue)` followed by `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`?

Comment: Also you should not use a concurrent queue as a Scheduler it has to be serial.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa In my real code, because I have some UI related code in my `sink`, in the example code, it's for simplify the testing, since `Set` is not thread safe.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa why we should not use a concurrent queue, do you have any doc about this?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa After I use serial queue, it works!! Thanks.
If you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It is quite scary how many values get lost in your example and never make it to receiveValue

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `Combine` expect schedulers to operate as serial queues, but DispatchQueue.global is concurrent.

If you declare you background queue like this:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "any name will do", qos: .background)
```

Everything will work as expected.

There is an interesting discussion about it on Swift forums:

https://forums.swift.org/t/runloop-main-or-dispatchqueue-main-when-using-combine-scheduler/26635