# Combine does not output value but only completion

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to understand behavior of Combine. When I `sink` to the Publisher I'm receiving from time to time `completion.finished` but I was expecting first `output` and then `completion`. I need to mention that I'm just learning Combine so maybe I'm doing something wrong. My publisher is created in this way:

```
private func createPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
    let upstreamQueue = DispatchQueue.global() // 1 DispatchQueue(label: "upstream-queue")
    return Deferred {
        Future { promise in // 2
            // calling promise in sync way
            // promise(.success("TestCompleted"))
            // OR in async way
            // upstreamQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(5)) {
            //     promise(.success("TestCompleted"))
            // }
            promise(.success("TestCompleted"))
        }
    }
    .subscribe(on: upstreamQueue)
    .delay(for: .milliseconds(100), tolerance: .milliseconds(10), scheduler: upstreamQueue) // 3
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Take a note that. Look at comments in above code. Numbers in comments described below:

1. `upstreamQueue` is concurrent in this case. When I create serial queue this problem does not occur. In documentation there is no word that this should be serial queue.
2. There is two possible way how to execute `promise`: `async` way according to docs this should be async but I tried both scenarios and no matter which is used the problem occur.
3. As far as I know and I was reading docs there is no word that in `delay` we should use serial queue so I used concurrent `upstreamQueue` as a scheduler here

Now the PROBLEM arises when I try to use this publisher. Here is the class that is trying to use it. The object is persisting during `load` calls so I can count executions. I'm also using helper local variable `stateDidSet` to build condition and to put breakpoint there to catch this undesired condition. Here is the consumer of the above Publisher.

```
public final class TestVM: ObservableObject {

    public enum VMState<T> {
        case loading
        case loaded(T)
        case error(message: String)
    }

    public typealias Publisher = AnyPublisher<String, Error>
    private let pub: Publisher
    private var disposable: AnyCancellable?
    private var loadCount = 0

    @Published public var state: VMState<String> = .loading

    public init() {
        self.pub = createPublisher()
    }

    public func load() {
        loadCount += 1
        print("load \(loadCount)")
        disposable?.cancel()
        var stateDidSet = false
        state = .loading

        disposable = pub
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { s in
                print("  receiveSubscription")
            }, receiveOutput: { output in
                print("  receiveOutput")
            }, receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("  receiveCompletion: \(completion)")
            }, receiveCancel: {
                print("  receiveCancel")
            }, receiveRequest: { demand in
                print("  receiveRequest: \(demand)")
            })
            .sink { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .failure:
                    self?.state = .error(message: "Got Failure")
                    stateDidSet = true
                    print("  completed with Failure")
                case .finished:
                    if !stateDidSet {
                        print("  completed without output or failure - WARNING") // 4 Breakpoint here
                        self?.state = .error(message: "Got completion withtout getting value or failure")
                    } else {
                        print("  completed")
                    }
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] output in
                self?.state = .loaded(output) // 5
                print("  loaded")
                stateDidSet = true
            }
    }
}
```

Calls to load functions are only executed when `state` is `.loaded` or `.error` state. No concurrent calls to it.

4. Breakpoint after condition that in my opinion should not be true all the times.
5. I'm expecting value and then completion. But I'm receiving from time to time only `completion.finished`

Does anyone have some idea why from time to time I'm not receiving value but only `completion` with `finished` result.

Example console output:

```
load 6
  receiveSubscription
  receiveRequest: unlimited
  receiveOutput
  loaded
  receiveCompletion: finished
  completed
load 7
  receiveSubscription
  receiveRequest: unlimited
  receiveOutput
  loaded
  receiveCompletion: finished
  completed
load 8
  receiveSubscription
  receiveRequest: unlimited
  receiveCompletion: finished
  completed without output or failure - WARNING
```

Comment: As you have noticed the solution is to use a serial queue. As you can see with concurrent queues there is no guarantee that the value will get published before completion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`Sink.receiveValue\` is not called after \`publisher.receive(on: backgroundQueue)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66030354/sink-receivevalue-is-not-called-after-publisher-receiveon-backgroundqueue)

Comment: This is not how one would usually use Combine in combination with an ObservableObject. Usually, in your initialiser you would establish the "pipes" and subscribe to it with `sink` which produces the output which will be published. Your Observable would have a function where you "send in" an input (via a PassthroughSubject), for example send in a URL, process it, publish result; repeat.

Comment: Actually couldn't one go even further and suggest that Combine is sort of dead at this point? I mean, I love Combine and wrote a free online book about it, but I am moving away from it completely at this point, in favor of `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred approach to implement your use case would be similar to this:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

final class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    enum State {
        case start
        case loading(URL)
        case finished(URL, Data)
        case error(Error)
    }

    @Published private(set) var state: State = .start
    
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!
    private let input: PassthroughSubject<URL, Never> = .init()
    
    init() {
        self.cancellable = input
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map { [weak self] url in
            self?.state = .loading(url)
            return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .map { (url, $0.data) }
        }
        .switchToLatest()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
            switch completion {
            case .finished: break
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.state = .error(error)
            }
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (url, data) in
            self?.state = .finished(url, data)
        })
    }
    
    func load() {
        input.send(URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!)
    }
    
}
```

Due to using `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` at the required places, this class effectively becomes confined to the main thread and thus has no data race issues. Alternatively, you can associate `Model` to the `@MainActor` and remove any `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`.

As I already mentioned in my comment, the approach is to build the "pipe" in the initialiser, then subscribe to it with `sink` and store the cancellable. This setup will be done only once. You also need to send in some data which gets processed in the pipe. In this case, it's a URL.

The operator sequence map/switchToLatest

```
... 
.map { url in
    return publisher(with: url)
.switchToLatest()
...
```

will guarantee that only *one* pending request can exist. If a request  arrives before the current request has been finished, the current will be cancelled and the new one will be started.

There's no need to use a Dispatch Queue, other than the one you want your Model to confine to (the main dispatch queue). You can call `load()` from any thread you want, the Model class is thread-safe and it publishes it state also on the main queue.